# Python Web Scraper - Table export to excel

Tags: python, scraper

**Hi guys,**

I've been using stackoverflow to learn how to write my first python script. I am actually building a webscraper and i need your help / opinion / lead to go further with my little project.

So far I could login into the website, access the right page, scrape all tables, put the data in a list, create an excel file

**I would like to:**

-instead of scraping all tables i would like to get just the third one in the html page

-export the list in the excel file

-to know if there is a solution to scrape the table as it is and export it to excel keeping the same format

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlwt import Workbook

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("XXXXX")


# username
userElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='user_name_register']")
userElem.clear()
userElem.send_keys('XXXXX')

# Password
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='password_register']")
passwordElem.clear()
passwordElem.send_keys('XXXXX')

# Tick - keep me logged in
keeploggedin=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='persistent_cookie_p_register']")
keeploggedin.click()

# Login click
login=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='login_form']/fieldset/ul/li[4]/div/button")
login.click()

# Go to URL
link = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
browser.get(link)

# Start scraping
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

lst = []
for tag in soup.find_all('table'):    ##IS THERE A WAY TO TAKE ONLY THE THIRD TABLE? I tried soup.find_all('table')[3] but it didn't work.
    txt = tag.text
    print(txt)
    lst.append(txt)

print(lst)

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Paris')

sheet1.write(0,0,'TEST2')

wb.save('Rate Browser.xls')
```

Comment: post url.......

Comment: if you want third element shouldn't you use 
`tags = soup.find_all('table')
tags[2]`  # ---- this will be your third table not tags[3] since counting starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @warl0ck it worked! 
I am going to pu the html code of the table. I can't put the link of the website since in work related. 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: no problem, i understand, since this has resolved your issue, i'll put this in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all('table')[3]` will not work because list is zero-based, so, use `soup.find_all('table')[2]`

Answer (score 0):

if you want third element you should use

```
tags = soup.find_all('table') 
tags[2]
```

> this will be your third table not tags[3] since counting starts from 0 not 1.